# is there a good example of using pywin32 createprocessasuser and getting the output?

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, win32com

I need to use the pywin32 method of creating a process as a different user and then get the stdout, the stderr and the error code from the spawned process as well as feed input into the process while it is running.  The problem is, I can't seem to find a very good example of this for the createprocess function.  This problem is further complicated by the fact that I need to run the subprocess as a different user and then get the stderr, stdout, feed in the stdin and retrieve the errorcode when it is done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are the ctypes definitions for the `CreateProcess` family of functions. I've written them to accompany the subsequent `create_process` wrapper function that uses `CREATIONINFO` and `STARTUPINFO` instances to control how the process is created and started, including which API is used.

I've integrated this into a subclass of `subprocess.Popen` that should work in both Python 2 and 3. Users of Python 2 will appreciate that it's Unicode as opposed to the legacy ANSI API that's used by 2.x subprocess. I also added the ability to create a process suspended and `start` it later. This is useful when you need to add a process to a Job object before it executes.

`CreateProcessAsUser` is normally called from a service that's running under the SYSTEM account, which has the required privilege `SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege`. You can use this process creation type with a local S4U (service for user) or Kerberos S4U logon token in Vista and later (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43114209/205580)), which is similar to how the Task Scheduler executes a scheduled task as a user without storing a password. An S4U logon via `LsaLogonUser` needs to be requested from an account with `SeTcbPrivilege` (trusted computer base), such as SYSTEM. Otherwise `LsaLogonUser` will return only an identification token that can't be used to create processes.

If the current user doesn't have `SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege`, then you can call `CreateProcessWithTokenW`, which instead requires `SeImpersonatePrivilege`. Administrators should have this privilege. Otherwise you can call `CreateProcessWithLogonW`, which doesn't require any privileges. The token and logon creation types also provide the option to automatically load the user's profile in the system registry.

The example that I've included below uses the logon creation type to run whoami.exe. It creates the process suspended with stdout as a pipe; starts it when you press enter; reads from stdout; and gets the exit code.

**ctypes definitions**

```
import os
import sys
import types
import ctypes
import subprocess

from ctypes import wintypes
from subprocess import PIPE

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
advapi32 = ctypes.WinDLL('advapi32', use_last_error=True)

ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE = 0x0006
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = wintypes.HANDLE(-1).value
INVALID_DWORD_VALUE = wintypes.DWORD(-1).value

DEBUG_PROCESS                    = 0x00000001
DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS          = 0x00000002
CREATE_SUSPENDED                 = 0x00000004
DETACHED_PROCESS                 = 0x00000008
CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE               = 0x00000010
CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP         = 0x00000200
CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT       = 0x00000400
CREATE_SEPARATE_WOW_VDM          = 0x00000800
CREATE_SHARED_WOW_VDM            = 0x00001000
INHERIT_PARENT_AFFINITY          = 0x00010000
CREATE_PROTECTED_PROCESS         = 0x00040000
EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT     = 0x00080000
CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB        = 0x01000000
CREATE_PRESERVE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL = 0x02000000
CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE        = 0x04000000
CREATE_NO_WINDOW                 = 0x08000000

STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW    = 0x00000001
STARTF_USESIZE          = 0x00000002
STARTF_USEPOSITION      = 0x00000004
STARTF_USECOUNTCHARS    = 0x00000008
STARTF_USEFILLATTRIBUTE = 0x00000010
STARTF_RUNFULLSCREEN    = 0x00000020
STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK  = 0x00000040
STARTF_FORCEOFFFEEDBACK = 0x00000080
STARTF_USESTDHANDLES    = 0x00000100
STARTF_USEHOTKEY        = 0x00000200
STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME  = 0x00000800
STARTF_TITLEISAPPID     = 0x00001000
STARTF_PREVENTPINNING   = 0x00002000

SW_HIDE            = 0
SW_SHOWNORMAL      = 1
SW_SHOWMINIMIZED   = 2
SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED   = 3
SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE  = 4
SW_SHOW            = 5
SW_MINIMIZE        = 6
SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7
SW_SHOWNA          = 8
SW_RESTORE         = 9
SW_SHOWDEFAULT     = 10 # ~STARTUPINFO
SW_FORCEMINIMIZE   = 11

LOGON_WITH_PROFILE        = 0x00000001
LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY = 0x00000002

STD_INPUT_HANDLE  = wintypes.DWORD(-10).value
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = wintypes.DWORD(-11).value
STD_ERROR_HANDLE  = wintypes.DWORD(-12).value

class HANDLE(wintypes.HANDLE):
    __slots__ = 'closed',

    def __int__(self):
        return self.value or 0

    def Detach(self):
        if not getattr(self, 'closed', False):
            self.closed = True
            value = int(self)
            self.value = None
            return value
        raise ValueError("already closed")

    def Close(self, CloseHandle=kernel32.CloseHandle):
        if self and not getattr(self, 'closed', False):
            CloseHandle(self.Detach())

    __del__ = Close

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%d)" % (self.__class__.__name__, int(self))

class PROCESS_INFORMATION(ctypes.Structure):
    """https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684873"""
    __slots__ = '_cached_hProcess', '_cached_hThread'

    _fields_ = (('_hProcess',   HANDLE),
                ('_hThread',    HANDLE),
                ('dwProcessId', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwThreadId',  wintypes.DWORD))

    @property
    def hProcess(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_cached_hProcess'):
            self._cached_hProcess = self._hProcess
        return self._cached_hProcess

    @property
    def hThread(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_cached_hThread'):
            self._cached_hThread = self._hThread
        return self._cached_hThread

    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self.hProcess.Close()
        finally:
            self.hThread.Close()

LPPROCESS_INFORMATION = ctypes.POINTER(PROCESS_INFORMATION)

LPBYTE = ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.BYTE)

class STARTUPINFO(ctypes.Structure):
    """https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331"""
    _fields_ = (('cb',              wintypes.DWORD),
                ('lpReserved',      wintypes.LPWSTR),
                ('lpDesktop',       wintypes.LPWSTR),
                ('lpTitle',         wintypes.LPWSTR),
                ('dwX',             wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwY',             wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwXSize',         wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwYSize',         wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwXCountChars',   wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwYCountChars',   wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwFillAttribute', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwFlags',         wintypes.DWORD),
                ('wShowWindow',     wintypes.WORD),
                ('cbReserved2',     wintypes.WORD),
                ('lpReserved2',     LPBYTE),
                ('hStdInput',       wintypes.HANDLE),
                ('hStdOutput',      wintypes.HANDLE),
                ('hStdError',       wintypes.HANDLE))

    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        self.cb = ctypes.sizeof(self)
        super(STARTUPINFO, self).__init__(**kwds)

class PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST(ctypes.Structure):
    pass

PPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST = ctypes.POINTER(PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST)

class STARTUPINFOEX(STARTUPINFO):
    _fields_ = (('lpAttributeList', PPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST),)

LPSTARTUPINFO = ctypes.POINTER(STARTUPINFO)
LPSTARTUPINFOEX = ctypes.POINTER(STARTUPINFOEX)

class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('nLength',              wintypes.DWORD),
                ('lpSecurityDescriptor', wintypes.LPVOID),
                ('bInheritHandle',       wintypes.BOOL))
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        self.nLength = ctypes.sizeof(self)
        super(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, self).__init__(**kwds)

LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES = ctypes.POINTER(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)

class HANDLE_IHV(HANDLE):
    pass

class DWORD_IDV(wintypes.DWORD):
    pass

def _check_ihv(result, func, args):
    if result.value == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return result.value

def _check_idv(result, func, args):
    if result.value == INVALID_DWORD_VALUE:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return result.value

def _check_bool(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return args

def WIN(func, restype, *argtypes):
    func.restype = restype
    func.argtypes = argtypes
    if issubclass(restype, HANDLE_IHV):
        func.errcheck = _check_ihv
    elif issubclass(restype, DWORD_IDV):
        func.errcheck = _check_idv
    else:
        func.errcheck = _check_bool

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211
WIN(kernel32.CloseHandle, wintypes.BOOL,
    wintypes.HANDLE,) # _In_ HANDLE hObject

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685086
WIN(kernel32.ResumeThread, DWORD_IDV,
    wintypes.HANDLE,) # _In_ hThread

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425
WIN(kernel32.CreateProcessW, wintypes.BOOL,
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpApplicationName
    wintypes.LPWSTR,        # _Inout_opt_ lpCommandLine
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,  # _In_opt_    lpProcessAttributes
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,  # _In_opt_    lpThreadAttributes
    wintypes.BOOL,          # _In_        bInheritHandles
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_        dwCreationFlags
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpEnvironment
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpCurrentDirectory
    LPSTARTUPINFO,          # _In_        lpStartupInfo
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)  # _Out_       lpProcessInformation

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429
WIN(advapi32.CreateProcessAsUserW, wintypes.BOOL,
    wintypes.HANDLE,        # _In_opt_    hToken
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpApplicationName
    wintypes.LPWSTR,        # _Inout_opt_ lpCommandLine
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,  # _In_opt_    lpProcessAttributes
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,  # _In_opt_    lpThreadAttributes
    wintypes.BOOL,          # _In_        bInheritHandles
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_        dwCreationFlags
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpEnvironment
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpCurrentDirectory
    LPSTARTUPINFO,          # _In_        lpStartupInfo
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)  # _Out_       lpProcessInformation

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682434
WIN(advapi32.CreateProcessWithTokenW, wintypes.BOOL,
    wintypes.HANDLE,        # _In_        hToken
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_        dwLogonFlags
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpApplicationName
    wintypes.LPWSTR,        # _Inout_opt_ lpCommandLine
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_        dwCreationFlags
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpEnvironment
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpCurrentDirectory
    LPSTARTUPINFO,          # _In_        lpStartupInfo
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)  # _Out_       lpProcessInformation

# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431
WIN(advapi32.CreateProcessWithLogonW, wintypes.BOOL,
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_        lpUsername
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpDomain
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_        lpPassword
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_        dwLogonFlags
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpApplicationName
    wintypes.LPWSTR,        # _Inout_opt_ lpCommandLine
    wintypes.DWORD,         # _In_        dwCreationFlags
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpEnvironment
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,       # _In_opt_    lpCurrentDirectory
    LPSTARTUPINFO,          # _In_        lpStartupInfo
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)  # _Out_       lpProcessInformation
```

**High-level wrapper**

```
CREATION_TYPE_NORMAL = 0
CREATION_TYPE_LOGON  = 1
CREATION_TYPE_TOKEN  = 2
CREATION_TYPE_USER   = 3

class CREATIONINFO(object):
    __slots__ = ('dwCreationType',
        'lpApplicationName', 'lpCommandLine', 'bUseShell',
        'lpProcessAttributes', 'lpThreadAttributes', 'bInheritHandles',
        'dwCreationFlags', 'lpEnvironment', 'lpCurrentDirectory',
        'hToken', 'lpUsername', 'lpDomain', 'lpPassword', 'dwLogonFlags')

    def __init__(self, dwCreationType=CREATION_TYPE_NORMAL,
                 lpApplicationName=None, lpCommandLine=None, bUseShell=False,
                 lpProcessAttributes=None, lpThreadAttributes=None,
                 bInheritHandles=False, dwCreationFlags=0, lpEnvironment=None,
                 lpCurrentDirectory=None, hToken=None, dwLogonFlags=0,
                 lpUsername=None, lpDomain=None, lpPassword=None):
        self.dwCreationType = dwCreationType
        self.lpApplicationName = lpApplicationName
        self.lpCommandLine = lpCommandLine
        self.bUseShell = bUseShell
        self.lpProcessAttributes = lpProcessAttributes
        self.lpThreadAttributes = lpThreadAttributes
        self.bInheritHandles = bInheritHandles
        self.dwCreationFlags = dwCreationFlags
        self.lpEnvironment = lpEnvironment
        self.lpCurrentDirectory = lpCurrentDirectory
        self.hToken = hToken
        self.lpUsername = lpUsername
        self.lpDomain = lpDomain
        self.lpPassword = lpPassword
        self.dwLogonFlags = dwLogonFlags

def create_environment(environ):
    if environ is not None:
        items = ['%s=%s' % (k, environ[k]) for k in sorted(environ)]
        buf = '\x00'.join(items)
        length = len(buf) + 2 if buf else 1
        return ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(buf, length)

def create_process(commandline=None, creationinfo=None, startupinfo=None):
    if creationinfo is None:
        creationinfo = CREATIONINFO()

    if startupinfo is None:
        startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
    elif isinstance(startupinfo, subprocess.STARTUPINFO):
        startupinfo = STARTUPINFO(dwFlags=startupinfo.dwFlags,
                        hStdInput=startupinfo.hStdInput,
                        hStdOutput=startupinfo.hStdOutput,
                        hStdError=startupinfo.hStdError,
                        wShowWindow=startupinfo.wShowWindow)

    si, ci, pi = startupinfo, creationinfo, PROCESS_INFORMATION()

    if commandline is None:
        commandline = ci.lpCommandLine

    if commandline is not None:
        if ci.bUseShell:
            si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
            si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE
            comspec = os.environ.get("ComSpec", os.path.join(
                        os.environ["SystemRoot"], "System32", "cmd.exe"))
            commandline = '"{}" /c "{}"'.format(comspec, commandline)
        commandline = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(commandline)

    dwCreationFlags = ci.dwCreationFlags | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT
    lpEnvironment = create_environment(ci.lpEnvironment)

    if (dwCreationFlags & DETACHED_PROCESS and
       ((dwCreationFlags & CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE) or
        (ci.dwCreationType == CREATION_TYPE_LOGON) or
        (ci.dwCreationType == CREATION_TYPE_TOKEN))):
        raise RuntimeError('DETACHED_PROCESS is incompatible with '
                           'CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, which is implied for '
                           'the logon and token creation types')

    if ci.dwCreationType == CREATION_TYPE_NORMAL:

        kernel32.CreateProcessW(
            ci.lpApplicationName, commandline,
            ci.lpProcessAttributes, ci.lpThreadAttributes, ci.bInheritHandles,
            dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, ci.lpCurrentDirectory,
            ctypes.byref(si), ctypes.byref(pi))

    elif ci.dwCreationType == CREATION_TYPE_LOGON:

        advapi32.CreateProcessWithLogonW(
            ci.lpUsername, ci.lpDomain, ci.lpPassword, ci.dwLogonFlags,
            ci.lpApplicationName, commandline,
            dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, ci.lpCurrentDirectory,
            ctypes.byref(si), ctypes.byref(pi))

    elif ci.dwCreationType == CREATION_TYPE_TOKEN:

        advapi32.CreateProcessWithTokenW(
            ci.hToken, ci.dwLogonFlags,
            ci.lpApplicationName, commandline,
            dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, ci.lpCurrentDirectory,
            ctypes.byref(si), ctypes.byref(pi))

    elif ci.dwCreationType == CREATION_TYPE_USER:

        advapi32.CreateProcessAsUserW(
            ci.hToken,
            ci.lpApplicationName, commandline,
            ci.lpProcessAttributes, ci.lpThreadAttributes, ci.bInheritHandles,
            dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, ci.lpCurrentDirectory,
            ctypes.byref(si), ctypes.byref(pi))

    else:
        raise ValueError('invalid process creation type')

    return pi
```

**Extend `subprocess.Popen`**

```
class Popen(subprocess.Popen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        ci = self._creationinfo = kwds.pop('creationinfo', CREATIONINFO())
        if kwds.pop('suspended', False):
            ci.dwCreationFlags |= CREATE_SUSPENDED
        self._child_started = False
        super(Popen, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)

    if sys.version_info[0] == 2:

        def _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
                           cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo,
                           creationflags, shell, to_close, p2cread, p2cwrite,
                           c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite):
            """Execute program (MS Windows version)"""
            commandline = (args if isinstance(args, types.StringTypes) else
                           subprocess.list2cmdline(args))
            self._common_execute_child(executable, commandline, shell, 
                    close_fds, creationflags, env, cwd,
                    startupinfo, p2cread, c2pwrite, errwrite, to_close)
    else:

        def _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
                           pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags,
                           shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread,
                           errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session):
            """Execute program (MS Windows version)"""
            assert not pass_fds, "pass_fds not supported on Windows."
            commandline = (args if isinstance(args, str) else
                           subprocess.list2cmdline(args))
            self._common_execute_child(executable, commandline, shell, 
                    close_fds, creationflags, env, cwd,
                    startupinfo, p2cread, c2pwrite, errwrite)

    def _common_execute_child(self, executable, commandline, shell,
                              close_fds, creationflags, env, cwd,
                              startupinfo, p2cread, c2pwrite, errwrite,
                              to_close=()):

        ci = self._creationinfo
        if executable is not None:
            ci.lpApplicationName = executable
        if commandline:
            ci.lpCommandLine = commandline
        if shell:
            ci.bUseShell = shell
        if not close_fds:
            ci.bInheritHandles = int(not close_fds)
        if creationflags:
            ci.dwCreationFlags |= creationflags
        if env is not None:
            ci.lpEnvironment = env
        if cwd is not None:
            ci.lpCurrentDirectory = cwd

        if startupinfo is None:
            startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
        si = self._startupinfo = startupinfo

        default = None if sys.version_info[0] == 2 else -1
        if default not in (p2cread, c2pwrite, errwrite):
            si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES
            si.hStdInput  = int( p2cread)
            si.hStdOutput = int(c2pwrite)
            si.hStdError  = int(errwrite)

        try:
            pi = create_process(creationinfo=ci, startupinfo=si)
        finally:
            if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
                if p2cread is not None:
                    p2cread.Close()
                    to_close.remove(p2cread)
                if c2pwrite is not None:
                    c2pwrite.Close()
                    to_close.remove(c2pwrite)
                if errwrite is not None:
                    errwrite.Close()
                    to_close.remove(errwrite)
            else:
                if p2cread != -1:
                    p2cread.Close()
                if c2pwrite != -1:
                    c2pwrite.Close()
                if errwrite != -1:
                    errwrite.Close()
                if hasattr(self, '_devnull'):
                    os.close(self._devnull)

        if not ci.dwCreationFlags & CREATE_SUSPENDED:
            self._child_started = True

        # Retain the process handle, but close the thread handle
        # if it's no longer needed.
        self._processinfo = pi
        self._handle = pi.hProcess.Detach()
        self.pid = pi.dwProcessId
        if self._child_started:
            pi.hThread.Close()

    def start(self):
        if self._child_started:
            raise RuntimeError("processes can only be started once")
        hThread = self._processinfo.hThread
        prev_count = kernel32.ResumeThread(hThread)
        if prev_count > 1:
            for i in range(1, prev_count):
                if kernel32.ResumeThread(hThread) <= 1:
                    break
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('cannot start the main thread')
        # The thread's previous suspend count was 0 or 1, 
        # so it should be running now.
        self._child_started = True
        hThread.Close()

    def __del__(self):
        if not self._child_started:
            try:
                if hasattr(self, '_processinfo'):
                    self._processinfo.hThread.Close()
            finally:
                if hasattr(self, '_handle'):
                    self.terminate()
        super(Popen, self).__del__()
```

**Example**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
        input = raw_input

    cmd = 'whoami.exe'
    ci = CREATIONINFO(CREATION_TYPE_LOGON,
                      lpUsername='test',
                      lpPassword='password')

    p = Popen(cmd, suspended=True, creationinfo=ci,
              stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

    print('Process Id: %d' % p.pid)
    print('Thread Id: %d' % p._processinfo.dwThreadId)

    assert not p._child_started
    input('Press enter to start')
    p.start()
    assert p._child_started

    print('\nOutput:')
    print(p.stdout.read())
    print('Exit Code: %d' % p.wait())
```

**Output**

```
Process Id: 6104
Thread Id: 1492
Press enter to start

Output:
domain\test

Exit Code: 0
```

Comment: This is a good example, but can I ask why the handles are closed after a process has been created.  What if I wanted to write to stdin of the process as well?

Comment: @RustyWeber, for `stdout` you want the child to inherit the pipe's write handle, while the current process uses the read handle, as I demonstrated. The standard handles inherited by the child can be closed once the process is created. You don't want them getting inherited again if you spawn a second process. If you set `stdin` to a pipe as well (remember to flip the pipe around; keep the write handle, and the child inherits the read handle), use separate threads to write to `stdin` and read from `stdout`, else you can end up in a deadlock scenario.

Comment: I've revised this answer to make it easier to use all 4 creation types and removed a lot of the cumbersome cruft by integrating it with a `Popen` subclass.